# $M$ balls, $N$ bins: how long until at least $1$ bin has $4$ balls

Tags: probability, markov-chains

So the problem set-up is as follows (not for a test or exam, just do not know how to compute it).

- I have $M$ (balls), in reality, $1.6$ billion
- I have $N$ (bins), in reality, $400$ million

Each bin can hold up to $4$ balls. How many balls (the expectation) must I throw until $1$ bin reaches max capacity at $4$ balls?

A ball is just as likely to land in bin #$1$ as it is in bin #$400$ million (provided it's not full).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: The straightforward approach is to consider it as a finite-state absorbing Markov chain.  We can model the transient states by four-tuples $(b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3)$ where $b_i$ is the number of bins with $i$ balls.  Since no state is ever repeated, we wouldn't actually use the machinery for absorbing Markov chains, but work backwards from the states nearest the goal.  If there are $N$ bins, we have $$b_0+b_1+b_2+b_3\leq N$$ and stars and bars tells us that there are $\binom{N+4}{4}$ transient states.  With $N=4\cdot10^8$, this is about $10^{33}$ states, so this naive approach is hopeless.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the bound on the number of balls doesn't matter, since by the time we add 1.6 billion balls we are guaranteed to have already made a bin reach max capacity. So let us deal with the problem where we have infinite balls.

Consider a 400 million dimensional space where we work in one positive quadrant/octant/?. Given any point $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_{400,000,000})$, we let it's value be the expected number of balls to throw until 1 bin reaches max capacity at 4 balls given that the number of balls in bin i is $4-a_i$. It is obvious that the value satisfies a recursion of the form (where || denotes valuation), $|(a_1, a_2, ..., a_{400,000,000})| = 1+\frac{|(a_1-1, a_2, ..., a_{400,000,000})|+|(a_1, a_2-1, ..., a_{400,000,000})|+|(a_1, a_2, a_3-1, ..., a_{400,000,000})|+...}{400,000,000}$ depending on which bin the ball falls into, where the expected value of a point n with any coordinate equal 0 is 0 (since it represents a bin is already full.)

We set up a generating function to represent this enormous sum, with the shorthand $x_?$ to represent $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{400,000,000}$.

We know that $A(x_?) = \frac{x_1x_2...x_{400,000,000}}{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)...(1-x_{400,000,000})}+A(x_?)\cdot\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_{400,000,000}}{400,000,00}$

So $A(x_?) = \frac{x_1x_2...x_{400,000,000}}{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)...(1-x_{400,000,000})(1-\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_{400,000,000}}{400,000,000})}$

We are looking for $[x_1^4x_2^4...x_{400,000,000}^4]$, or

$[x_1^3x_2^3...x_{400,000,000}^3]\frac{1}{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)...(1-x_{400,000,000})(1-\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_{400,000,000}}{400,000,000})} = \frac{1}{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)...(1-x_{400,000,000})}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_{400,000,000}}{400,000,000}}$

We notice that $\frac{1}{(1-x_1)(1-x_2)...(1-x_{400,000,000})}$ is the multidimensional partial sum product, meaning our answer is simply a multidimensional partial sum version of the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_{400,000,000}}{400,000,000}}$

In particular, this can be visualized as a hypercube in our 400,000,000 dimensional space inscribed in our right isoceles hyperpyramid.

The problem is now reduced to computing the sum of valuations in the inscribed hypercube.

In particular, this valuation system is of ordered structure, so we measure using Exponential Generating functions. Denote $D_n = [\frac{x^n}{n!}]$. We are looking for $D_0+D_1x+...D_{1,200,000,000}x^{1,200,000,000} (1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6})^{400,000,000}$.

With all due complexity from the structure of the cut hypercube in the multinomial version of pascal's triangle, we proceed through pure computation and multinomial theorem. We will substitute N for 400,000,000 for simplicity and general case computation.

$\text{Answer} = \sum \limits_{k=0} \sum \limits_{a+2b+3c=k, a+b+c \leq N} {a+b+c \choose a, b, c}\cdot \frac{1}{2^b} \cdot \frac{1}{6^c} \cdot (-1)^{a+b+c} \cdot (a+2b+3c)! \cdot \frac{1}{400^{a+2b+3c}}$

By eliminating summations and simplifying, our answer is... drumroll...

$\boxed{\sum \limits_{a+b+c \leq N} \frac{(a+b+c)!(a+2b+3c)!}{a!b!c!N^a(2N^2)^b(6N^3)^c}  \text{ for nonnegative a, b, c.}}$

Which is our exact formula for general values of N, coming from 3 subsequent bijections (and a lot of pen and paper). So yeah, I highly doubt the existence of a closed formula for general N **without** summations. I've done my best here and there is only one summation remaining. Hope this is good enough for you!

In fact, I can also give you a super general formula that allows us to set the box capacity, say L. Here, $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{L-1}$ are nonnegative integers.

$\boxed{\boxed{\sum \limits_{\sum \limits_{i=1}^{L-1}x_i \leq N} \frac{(\sum \limits_{i=1}^{L-1}x_i)!(\sum \limits_{i=1}^{L-1}ix_i)!}{\prod \limits_{i=1}^{L-1} (x_i!(i!N^i)^{x_i})}}}$

Answer (score 1):

After $m$ balls, the number in any given bin is Poisson with parameter $\lambda=m/N$, so the probability it contains 4 is $\lambda^4/(24\exp(\lambda))$.
The probability that none of them have reached that is roughly
$$\left(1-\frac{\lambda^4}{24\exp(\lambda)}\right)^N$$
When $m=kN^{3/4}$,  so $\lambda=kN^{-1/4}$, this is roughly $$\exp(-k^4/24)$$